# How to store OpenSSL keys

Tags: security, openssl

I have a private and a public key in my Linux system. What is the best way to store the private key? Is there a proper directory? Do I need to create a user to own the key? How to improve the key protection?

Comment: If you told us what the keys were used for, what software used them, what your operational processes were for deploying keys & enabling access to the private key, then we might be in a position to make sensible suggestions - but providing a competent answer would require a lot more discussion than is appropriate here - voting to close as too broad.

Comment: IMHO, your question is a better fit for [Security.SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: This might help you along: [linux private key "best practice"](http://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=linux+private+key+%22best+practice%22)

Answer (score 2):

If you're just storing keys (don't need them for any application on that host), it's common practice to store them somewhere inside your HOME directory (bonus if you're the superuser), restricting permissions to `u=r,go=` (or `0400`). **Private keys are better protected if stored as [PKCS #12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) (encrypted format), preferably using a strong password**.

**CAUTION**: These simple practices alone don't guarantee your host won't be compromised, allowing an attacker to retrieve your certs/keys when you decrypt & use them.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to store a private key is in a smart card or hardware security module. It can be used, but never stolen that way.

The next best place is by using access control. Have it owned and readable only by you and readable only by the process that needs to read it.